# Connect Local database to asp.net C#

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error while opening the connection. I am working on windows application.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Can u please let me know how to get connected to Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5(.NET Framework). I have vs 2008.

Comment: You have solved this query..?

Answer (score 0):

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=PATH/TO/SDF";
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
string command1 = "sql goes here"
con.Open();
SqlCeCommand sqlcom1 = new SqlCeCommand(command1, con);
SqlCeDataReader reader = sqlcom1.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Still the same error remains. What is difference between SqlCommand and SqlCeCommand

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps you should make sure you're doing them right:

> 1. Make sure your server name is correct, e.g., no typo on the name.
> 2. Make sure your instance name is correct and there is actually such
>      an instance on your target machine. [Update: Some application converts
>      \ to . If you are not sure about your application, please try both
>      Server\Instance and Server\Instance in your connection string]
> 3. Make sure the server machine is reachable, e.g, DNS can be resolve
>      correctly, you are able to ping the server (not always true).
> 4. Make sure SQL Browser service is running on the server.
> 5. If firewall is enabled on the server, you need to put sqlbrowser.exe and/or UDP port
>      1434 into exception.

Source: http://goo.gl/MZJx

And also I believe this tutorial is a good start to identify the error throughly and easily:

Link : http://goo.gl/3unpa